# What is the title for the head of a county?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, vocabulary

As the head of a city is called *mayor*, what is the proper **single** word to title the head of a county? Answers from any country are welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that questions on this site should include the initial research you have attempted— say, a web search. A *county* is a wildly different unit in different countries, and even within a single country, they have different forms. Counties in many U.S. states have no "head" official at all. **There is no single term for the head of a county**.

Comment: Thanks choster! I did google it but only got "county executive" as Richard has suggested below. I was looking for a concise single term as "mayor" is. It's still good to know there isn't one. I will include more background next time I ask a question.

Comment: The word "county" refers to a piece of land ruled over by a count, which was a medieval noble title. Just because many lands have lost such rulership, doesn't change how they were formed.

Comment: Many U.S. counties have no executive. Most have a board, who may elect a *chair* or a *president*. They may hire a professional county *manager* or *administrator*. In some states, the county *commissioner* or *commissioners* have power. In Kentucky, the position is known as *Judge/Executive*, and in New Jersey, which also has county executives, managers, and administrators, there are *freeholder directors*. Some counties have *mayors*, or their chief executive is the mayor of the city with which they are consolidated. But these are all different offices with different roles and powers.

Comment: Moreover, a *county* is a very different type of region in different countries. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/County .

Answer (score 3):

A common term in the U.S. is *county executive* or simply *executive*. That's the term used in Montgomery County, Maryland, U.S.A., where I live.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isiah_Leggett):

> Isiah "Ike" Leggett (born July 25, 1944) is an American politician
>   from the U.S. state of Maryland, currently serving as the *executive* of
>   Montgomery County, Maryland.

Also from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/County_executive):

> A county *executive* is the head of the executive branch of government
>   in a United States county.

Comment: Thanks Richard! Can I also say vice county executive?

Comment: @EaminZhang That role doesn't exist in my county. Nor is there a "deputy executive". You can review the staffing of the Office of the County Executive [here](http://www.montgomerycountymd.gov/exec/staff.html).

Comment: Common, but far from universal; I would wager that more states have county administrators or county managers, and note that many counties in many states do not have an executive.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for answering with so much helpful details.

Comment: @EaminZhang My pleasure. I would argue that *executive* is one word. :-)

Comment: @RichardKayser It is the most concise way of saying it I've heard so far, but I can just say "mayor" without any context and people know I'm talking about the head of a city.

Comment: @EaminZhang Then you were right up above in one of your comments: there isn't one word.

Comment: @choster I wouldn't be surprised. After all, it's federalism.

Comment: @choster I checked out a few additional counties: Westchester County, NY; Cuyahoga County, OH; Cook County, IL; and Harris County, TX. The first two have county executives; the third has a chief executive officer who serves as the president of the Board of Commissioners; and the fourth appears to have four commissioners but no single executive.

Answer (score 2):

Also, *chair* and *vice-chair* of the county legislature.  That's what the positions are called in my county.

You could say "county supervisor", I think, and people would understand what you're saying. But you need to recognize that the county is usually not the most influential governing body, so it doesn't have a very majestic leader title.

Comment: Thanks for answering! *Chair* is a very generic term though.

Comment: @EaminZhang - What can I say?  That's what the positions are called in my county.  You could say "county supervisor", I think, and people would understand what you're saying.  But you need to recognize that the *county* is usually not the most influential governing body, so it doesn't have a very majestic leader title.

Comment: @EaminZhang - If it doesn't have to be the county, then you could safely use *mayor*.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: @aparente001 Why not find the definitions of the words and see if you can find recorded instances id their usage?

Comment: It may still help other readers if you document a usage from personal experience. You can take your comment, that the position is so-called in your county, and usefully add it to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here where I live we have mayors of our counties. I don't think we have vice mayors - for example, I live in a county called Clark, and we have the mayor of Clark County, the governor of my state. We also have a mayor of our city as well. Yep, this can be confusing. Looking at Wikipedia yields more confusing results. I've never heard of county executive.

Comment: Good to learn how one title can be used for various positions in different governments. I used to believe "governor" is only for a state or colony.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please explain your answer, preferably with some supporting statements and references. While opinions are valued, they are not of much help as answers.

Comment: @EaminZhang Welcome to the Internet.

Comment: I checked out a few Clark counties. Nevada: Commissioners, Missouri: Commissions, Washington: Councilors, Wisconsin: Commissioners, Ohio: Commissioners, Kansas: Commissioners, Kentucky: Judge/Executive (note @choster above), Illinois: Board members, South Dakota: Commissioners, Indiana: Commissioners, ... Note that Cuyahoga County, Ohio has has an executive, from which one can infer that even within a given state, counties may be run differently. Note also that counties may have vastly different populations, which could affect the structure of the county government.